# Error in ovirt_disk module via ansible AWX

Tags: ansible

I'm getting below wired error when trying to add disk to RHVM. I have checked in the documentation. all parameters seems legit to me. I need extra eye to valiate this case. thank you in-advanced

**error msg as follows**

> "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ovirt_disk) module: activate Supported parameters include: auth, bootable, description, download_image_path, fetch_nested, force, format, id, image_provider, interface, logical_unit, name, nested_attributes, openstack_volume_type, poll_interval, profile, quota_id, shareable, size, sparse, sparsify, state, storage_domain, storage_domains, timeout, upload_image_path, vm_id, vm_name, wait"
>   }

**Parameters in the role as follows**

```
        "module_args": {
        "vm_name": "Jxyxyxyxy01",
        "activate": true,
        "storage_domain": "Data-xxx-Txxx",
        "description": "Created using Jira ticket CR-329",
        "format": "cow",
        "auth": {
            "timeout": 0,
            "url": "https://xxxxxx.com/ovirt-engine/api",
            "insecure": true,
            "kerberos": false,
            "compress": true,
            "headers": null,
            "token": "xxcddsvsdvdsvsdvdEFl0910KES84qL8Ff5NReA",
            "ca_file": null
        },
        "state": "present",
        "sparse": true,
        "interface": "virtio_scsi",
        "wait": true,
        "size": "20GiB",
        "name": "Jxyxyxyxy01_123"
    }
```

**Playbook as follows.**

```
 - name: Create New Disk size of {{ disk_size }} on {{ hostname }} using storage domain {{ vm_storage_domain }}
   ovirt_disk:
      auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
      description: "Created using Jira ticket {{ issueKey }}"
      storage_domain:  "{{ vm_storage_domain }}"
      name: "{{ hostname }}_123" # name of the disk
      vm_name: "{{ hostname }}" #name of the virtual machine
      interface: "virtio_scsi"
      size: "{{ disk_size }}GiB"
      sparse: yes
      format: cow
      activate: yes
      wait: yes
      state: present
   register: vm_disk_results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`activate` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ovirt_disk_module.html#parameter-activate) was added in ansible 2.8.

Upgrade your ansible installation or drop that parameter.

Comment: Thank you This is the extract issue. Its working after removing the parameter